# Return 404 if added anything at the end of URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, redirect

I am having strange problem, I have a website I am working on and below is one of the URL.

https://www.mechanical3dmodelling.com/industrial-equipment.php

Where if i add any characters at the end of URL (e.g. https://www.mechanical3dmodelling.com/industrial-equipment.phpaadf) it will return 404 Error which is completely fine.

But if i add numbers (e.g. https://www.mechanical3dmodelling.com/industrial-equipment.php111) it makes url https://www.mechanical3dmodelling.com/industrial-equipment.php/111/ and keeps me on same page.

I want this to act same as earlier example i.e. it should also return 404 if i add numbers too.

Below is my htaccess

==================

```
    ServerSignature Off
    Options +FollowSymlinks

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http\://lifehac?er\.com/ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    </IfModule>


    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
    RewriteRule (.*) $1?
```

===========================

for the reference, website is developed using Wordpress with Custom Permalinks plugin added.

Any help?

Regards
Manoj Soni

Comment: Can you post your .htacess rules

Comment: added htaccess and updated post also with more details